# Center y-axis on different # than 0 [Google Sheets/Excel]

Tags: excel, google-sheets, data-visualization

Is there a way to center the y-axis at 0.30 instead of 0 in Google Sheets or Excel?
So for example, in the chart I have right now pasted here, I want the first bar (0.26) to face downward (i.e. flipped downward like a negative number would on a normal axis) since it is less than 0.3. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Calculate the difference between the value and 0.3 then relate the arrow to that. May need to add another data series and only show the arrow perhaps make the rest of the series transparent.

Comment: Do you mean to perform this operation via the UI or the Sheets API?

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting "Horizontal Axis Crosses" at axis value "0.30" in the Y axis options.

[image]